# I dont how to properly run this Docker Image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

guys

I followed the official tutorial about docker-compose and rails

[Official Tutorial -  Rails , Docker-Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/)
And I successfully run rails project by `docker-compose up` ,

But , just after finishing it , I pushed my image onto Docker hub

,because I want to run on other server by pulling this image from Docker hub

So in another server ,  I run  `docker pull user/repo` to pull the image from docker hub

And run `docker images` , I see my repo , it pulled successfully.

Then is my question , I don't know how I should do next to get my rails running just as it ran on previous server...

I've tried many ways from Google , but I still don't know hot should I do :<

Comment: try with something like `docker run -d -P user/repo`, then check if the container is running `docker ps`. If not the check the logs of your containers `docker logs <container id>` (you can get the id with `docker ps -a`)

Comment: Thank for your advise , but I get `Switch to inspect mode.`  when I run docker logs <>

Comment: ah it seems to be an open issue https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/285